# Appending dicts to a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.7

Consider below list:

```py
column = list()
```

I have a Python script, that iterates over a PDF file, converts each page to an image, and then for each page I further crop it according to "columns" I have defined. For each cropped part, I output the text content with OCR (tesseract).

My PDF file is two pages long, and this is the content:

```
#Page 1
Page 1 - Col 1.         Page 1 - Col 2.

#Page 2
Page 2 - COl 1.         Page 1 - Col 2.
```

Consider below array `images` of pages in my pdf file.

```py
{0: 'pdfpage_1.png', 1: '/pdfpage_2.png'}
```

And below column-areas defined `documentColumns`:

```
{'0': {'position': '30'}, '1': {'position': '60'}}
```

```py
# Make table layout for each page (in images{})
for idx, (key, image) in enumerate(images.items()):
    firstWidth = 0
    #On each page, crop it according to my columns.
    for i, col in enumerate(documentColumns):
        columnPos = documentColumns.get(str(col))
        pixelsrightcorner = round(width * (float(columnPos['position']) / 100))
        area = (firstWidth, 0, pixelsrightcorner, float(height))

        image_name = str(idx) + '_' + str(i + 1) + '.png'

        output_image = img.crop(area)
        output_image.save(image_name, image_type.upper())
        cmd = [TESSERACT, image_name, '-', 'quiet']

        proc = subprocess.Popen(
        cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0, text=True, shell=False)
        out, err = proc.communicate()
```

Now `out` returns the text found on the image. I then say, in the same loop, for each line in the returned text, add it to my list:

```py
for line in out.splitlines():
    column.append({str(i): str(line)})

# Create JSON file.
f = open('myfile.json', "w+")
f.write(json.dumps(column))
f.close()
```

Above generates this:

```
[{
    "0": "Page 1 - Col 1."
}, {
    "0": ""
}, {
    "1": "Page 1 - Col 2."
}, {
    "1": ""
}, {
    "0": "Page 2 - Col 1."
}, {
    "0": ""
}, {
    "1": "Page 2 - Col 2."
}, {
    "1": ""
}]
```

## Expected output

I am trying to read each page "from left to right". This means that the final output should be a list of dicts, where each dict represents a new row, that contains `n` number of columns like:

```
[{
    "0": "Page 1 - Col 1.",
    "1": "Page 1 - Col 2."
},{
    "0": "",
    "1": ""
},{
    "0": "Page 2 - Col 1.",
    "1": "Page 2 - Col 2."
},{
    "0": "",
    "1": ""
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare an array instead list and go to adding the dicts

```
column = []
```

After in the loop

```
node = {}

for line in out.splitlines():
    node[str(i)] = str(line)

column.append(node)
```